# Different ways to get italic formatting?

Tags: support, formatting, markdown

[image]

Seems familiar, doesn't it?

But when I type something like *this*
Italic was caused by a pair of single *
since it should be pair of double **

Is this normal?

Answer (score 4):

The [formatting help page](https://chess.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) gives these examples:

```
*This is italicized*, and so is _this_.
**This is bold**, and so is __this__.
Use ***italics and bold together*** if you ___have to___.
```

which render as

*This is italicized*, and so is *this*.
**This is bold**, and so is **this**.
Use ***italics and bold together*** if you ***have to***.

So: one asterisk or underscore for italic, two for bold.

The small box in the sidebar only gives some examples of markup, it is not a comprehensive reference.

Comment: https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet very good an visual reference for markdown